# Assembling an HTML string in JS is freezing website

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a chatbot frontend. This of course includes a chat window, which can be put on any website. For this reason, I am forced to create this window in JavaScript.

I require a function `updateView()` which I have coded as follows:

```
    
    var container = "<div style = 'position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; color: blue;'>";
    var feed = document.getElementById("feed");
    var lines = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("lines"));
    
    var i = 0;
    while (i < lines.length)
    {

        if(lines[i][0] == 0)
        {
            container += "<div style = 'background-color: crimson; height: auto; width: 100%;> <div style = 'position: absolute; right:0; top: 50%; background-color: crimson; height: auto; width: 60%;>" + lines[i][1]+ "</div></div>";

        }
        else if(lines[i][0] == 1)
        {
            container += "<div style = 'background-color: blue; height: auto; width: 100%;><div style = 'position: absolute; left:0; top: 50%; background-color: blue; height: auto; width: 60%;>" + lines[i][1] "</div></div>";
        }

        i ++;
    }
    container += "</div>";
    feed.innerHTML = container;
```

This code does perform its basic function of rendering the list of lines into feed, however, it freezes all interactive Elements of the chat window (textarea, scroll function of feed, and button).

I've already given all the functions I call alerts with debugging messages and have thus determined, that there is not any infinite loof running.

I assume there to be some newbie mistake somewhere. Please advise.

Comment: From my experience, while loops generally freeze web pages unless done in a very specific way.

Comment: Are you sure there are no infinite loops? Alerts pause the executing thread until dismissed.

Comment: Please edit your question and include what the data in `sessionStorage` would be.

Comment: Are the frozen elements inside `feed`?

Comment: How often does that code run?